# Cabal cannot install postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2

Tags: haskell, cabal

Both `cabal install postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2` and 
`cabal install --reinstall postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2` didnt work

```
Configuring postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2...
setup.exe: The program pg_config is required but it could not be found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Note: I am on local

Comment: sudo make me a sandwich?

Comment: @GradyPlayer: it looks like Windows to me. (`setup.exe`)

Comment: oh yeah, `sudo.exe` :) ... shivers

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need the external program `pg_config` which presumably comes with postgres. Make sure that postgres is installed correctly and all of its binaries are in your path.

I'm assuming you're on Windows, in which case install the postgres bindings is tricky. Take a look at instructions [here](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/pull/66) and [here](https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-postgresql/wiki/WindowsInstall) which are for libraries that *depend* on `postgresql-libpq` and make sure that you followed all the relevant steps.

The most relevant part to your current problem is updating your `Path` variable and adding something like `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin`, as detailed in the first link.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to install postgres for the correct CPU architecture from: http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ and after that adding the bin folder to the system path.

Comment: This solved my issue.  I use Cygwin to run **fish shell**, and faced issue while building `postgresql-libpq`.  Installing both `libpq-devel` and `postgresql-devel` via Cygwin installer does not solved it.  After I have installed **PostgreSQL for Windows** the issue was resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: On dockerized Debian 8 Jessie I had to install `postgresql-server-9.4` among with `libpq-dev` to resolve same issue